# Can Drools 6 Workbench push to a remote git repository?

Tags: git, drools, jbpm, workbench

I wanted to set up Workbench to use a git daemon shared by other developers who are using the Eclipse plugin.

I can clone the repository into Workbench, but it will not push changes back to that repository. It seems to use that clone to set up its own local repository.

Is this a limitation with Workbench? If we want to use Workbench and the Eclipse plugin in a mixed environment, do we have to use Workbench as the git daemon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no functionality in KIE Workbench as yet to push to a remote repo. However, you can still achieve your goal of having an upstream repository rather than letting all developers using the git repo inside the KIE Workbench. You can test it with the existing jbpm-playground repo. Let's assume you have created a fork on Github -

```
    git@github.com:yourGithubUsername/jbpm-playground.git.
```

and that you and your developers want to work primarily from the forked Github repo on a branch called "devBranch", but non-developers want to work primarily on the KIE Workbench.

You could manage that relationship between the Workbench's git repo and the upstream repo like this:

1. Initial setup

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:yourGithubUsername/jbpm-playground.git
   cd jbpm-playground
   git branch devBranch
   git checkout devBranch
   git push origin devBranch
   git remote add git-in-kiewb ssh://krisv@your-jbpm-server:8001/jbpm-playground
   ```
2. Getting changes by your non-developers from the git repo in KIE Workbench into your Github repo:

   ```
   git pull git-in-kiewb master
   git push origin devBranch
   ```
3. Getting changes by your developers from your Github repo into the git repo in KIE Workbench:

   ```
   git pull origin devBranch
   git push git-in-kiewb master
   ```

Answer (score 2):

for using master branch

```html
git clone git@github.com:tenkyu/drools-flow-order.git
cd drools-flow-order
git remote add git-in-kiewb ssh://admin@0.0.0.0:8002/saglik

->github
git pull git-in-kiewb master
git push origin master

->local
git pull origin master
git push git-in-kiewb master
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use git hooks to do this as explained here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap_repository_hooks

Basically create on your git repo on jboss, and there add a hook on post-commit, that could do git push origin.